# Apache2 / Cloudflare Error 521

Tags: ssl, configuration, vps, apache2, cloudflare

My apache2 server encountered a error: "502 Bad Gateway".

I started using ExpressJS and this happened.

Im doing this because I need to use pug and other backend utilities.
Here is my apache2 configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName shieldbotlist.tk
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://64.52.84.31:443/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://64.52.84.31:443/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

Comment: Sending http to port 443 may be problematic.  Sure your ExpressJS is listening on 64.52.84.31:443?  If it is, I'd try https:// 64.52.84.31/ .

Comment: Alright ill try it! Thanks for taking your time to look in this post!